# Why does pronunciation of spells matter?

Tags: harry-potter, spells, pronunciation, hermione-granger

Obviously, spells in Harry Potter can be cast nonverbally as well as verbally.  In the first year Charms class, they haven't gotten up to nonverbal spells yet.  But as they are trying to cast *Wingardium Leviosa*, Hermione tells Ron that the reason he can't cast the spell is because he's pronouncing it incorrectly.  If the spell can be cast nonverbally, and therefore with no pronunciation at all, why should pronunciation matter for the verbal spell?

**If you can cast spells by only thinking something, why does the pronunciation matter if you talk while you think it?**

Comment: I'm no neurologist, but I wouldn't be so sure that pronunciation doesn't matter when "thinking" a word. Any way, excellent question!

Comment: Another example of pronunciation matters is when Cho said Expellimelius and set her friends hair on fire.  Oops.

Comment: Have you ever done any computer programming?  `myVar` and `MyVar` aren't the same object. ;)

Comment: I would guess that a wand's speech recognition isn't quite as good as a human's.  Plus, human languages sometimes work that way too.  Put the emphasis on the wrong syllable, and suddenly you're telling your girlfriend's parents that you're glad to penis them.

Comment: just watch these verio serious and documented comics, this might give you some material to make your research on. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWtO0cfgewY  
Ps: this was irony.

Comment: Tried to edit to clarify the question

Comment: "In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God." (John 1:1) Names are important, words are important, it's easier to cast most spells when you you use the correct words. That's an old idea -- vide https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logos. Man gave names to all animals, so expressing our power over them, over nature. Name taboos are also very common through human history -- You-Know-Who just one of them. 'Fiat Lux', even God had to use the proper words now and then. Not to mention Baruffio...

Comment: @Draco18s they are in some languages...

Comment: @FreeMan That's true, but I think the point made still stands: in the case of magic, pronunciation is syntax.  Different pronunciation is a different keyword.

Comment: @DavidBanner Uh oh.  You're asking for trouble.  God can create stuff with a thought, so why did he need to say things like "let there be light?"  And did his pronunciation matter?  I mean he's perfect, so he probably pronounced it perfectly.  But if he hadn't, would it not have worked?  Questions.

Comment: @MishaRosnach Isn't that kind of like asking about typos in the Qur’an? I.e., if God had said it in any other way (that we somehow magically knew about), then _that way_ would simply have been how the Bible claims you say “Let there be light”. Or something like that. The Bible is pretty retconned anyway…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well, no, actually. The Quran is supposedly the literal word of God. I mean you can go to Afghanistan and find Pashto-speaking people who don't know a word of Arabic and yet can recite the entire Quran in its original Arabic language. Whereas the Bible makes no fuss about Classical Hebrew or Aramaic pronunciation. Just the story there - no way to know what spell God cast.

Comment: https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1655/25120457785_919334873a.jpg

Comment: Think of the difference between Diagon Alley and "diagonally" :-)

Comment: @Draco18s And syntax also matters. Call it an undeclared symbol, a syntax error, it doesn't really matter because it will fail regardless. But in the case of HP I seem to recall that not correct pronunciation might have an effect but the wrong effect. Something about a rhyme explaining this, even. Maybe to do with a troll or rhino? I can't recall what creature but you surely know what I refer to. Either way an error is an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes pronunciation maters.

> “STUBEFY !” Neville shouted again, pointing his wand at each
>   Death Eater in turn, “STUBEFY ! STUBE —”

At this point we know neville is competent enough to use stupefy but because of his broken nose he cant pronounce it right, and nothing happens.

I believe that when producing non-verbal spells the caster is also THINKING the incantation in their head. will update with a link to confirm .

> "Pointing his wand at nothing in particular, he gave it an upward flick and said Levicorpus! inside his head. "Aaaaaaaargh!" There was a flash of light and the room was full of voices: Everyone had woken up as Ron had let out a yell. Harry sent Advanced Potion-Making flying in panic; Ron was dangling upside down in midair as though an invisible hook had hoisted him up by the ankle.

@davidbanner, thanks for finding this, as we can see you say the word in your head, so if you cant pronounce it properly verbally, your probably will fail to cast in non-verbally since you have the wrong pronunciation in your mind.

Comment: I get that pronunciation matters, but why?  And how does that translate to nonverbal spells?

Comment: Here is a quote from The Half-Blood Prince, Harry casting the Levicorpus spell => "Pointing his wand at nothing in particular, he gave it an upward flick and said Levicorpus! inside his head. "Aaaaaaaargh!" There was a flash of light and the room was full of voices: Everyone had woken up as Ron had let out a yell. Harry sent Advanced Potion-Making flying in panic; Ron was dangling upside down in midair as though an invisible hook had hoisted him up by the ankle.

Comment: Leviorpus can only be cast nonverbally. What does that prove?

Comment: Are you saying that if he had pronounced it wrong inside his head, it wouldn't have worked?

Comment: "[Hermione] raised her wand, pointed it at Harry and whispered, 'Levicorpus.'" levicorpus can be used verbally, snape was writing it in a year 6 book, when he was using nonverbal spells. and yes if like ron with wingaurdium leviosa did not actually know the proper incantation, the spell would have failed

Comment: The Neville quote is interesting, though. Even with a broken nose, Neville should be perfectly capable of ‘pronouncing’ the spell correctly _in his head_. So unlike in Ron’s case, where he's basically using the wrong word both internally and externally because he doesn't yet _know_ the correct form, Neville _knows_ the thing to say and is presumably thinking it correctly in his head—it's a purely physical restriction that ruins it for him, which (I believe) it shouldn't. Would someone with a lisp or harelip be unable to cast verbal spells that contain an s, for example? Hardly.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think this is why they have so much trouble with non-verbal spells to start with, because their internal thought process isnt as clear as we think, so when they mispeak the spell, its because they arnt focusing internally enough on the spell.

Answer (score 5):

As I see it (this is just my interpretation as a reader), mastering spells seems to have levels. Much like Beginner, Novice, Advanced, Legendry, etc:

**Beginner level:**

Beginner stage. Mostly the first, second and third years. They are in the learning phase. And they need to perfect their wand movement and pronounce the spells properly in order to execute them well.

**Novice and advanced level:**

The seniors. A very wide band. Most of the people in the magical world fall in these levels. Easy-to-execute spells and charms can be done with the swish of the wand.

Like, for example, Mrs. Weasely sets the washing process of the utensils with a small flick of her wand, etc. Prof. Lupin making the kettle brew coffee with a flick of his wand.

Mostly the mundane work can be done with a small flick or minimal effort. McGonagall waves the wand very lazily(to conjure up plates) when Harry and Ron had to have their feast in her office.

**Advanced level:**

Doing advanced level magic with just a flick of a wand. People like Mc Gonagall, Dumbledore, Voldemort, etc.

For example, Dumbledore conjured up hundreds of sleeping bags with just a swish of his wand (in PoA), and so does McGonagall.

If there's a God Level, then it should be Dumbledore and Voldemort.

(However, insanely powerful spells(or curses) like *Avada Kedavra* takes a huge effort to pull off non-verbally, even for Voldemort).

For example, this quote from the Order of the Phoenix shows how powerful  Dumbledore and Voldemort are, even with non-verbal spells:

> "Dumbledore flicked his own wand: the force of the spell that emanated
>   from it was such that Harry though shielded by his golden guard, felt
>   his hair stand on end as it passed and, this time, Voldemort was forced
>   to conjure a shining silver shield out of thin air to deflect it"