# Is it possible to cast spells while sleeping?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

Since wandwork is not absolutely necessary to cast spells, is it possible for a wizard to accidentally cast spells while asleep, akin to sleepwalking or nocturnal emission?

Comment: Related: [Why does pronunciation of spells matter?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/116235/68872)

Comment: Can you please clarify exactly what you mean by 'spell'?

Comment: @Mithrandir I guess I mean verbally or gesturally-induced magic -- magic that is endogenous to the caster. Not something like potion-making that relies on external components.

Comment: Do you mean it has to require a movement/sound? What do you think about my answer?

Comment: @Mithrandir Yeah, I'm thinking along the lines of sleepwalking, where the wizard actually verbalizes the spell in the waking-world, but is asleep, not that he simply *dreams* about casting the spell or has a magical property that auto-casts a spell, like an auto-heal.

Comment: Please see [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94517/how-did-harry-get-his-hair-cut-at-hogwarts?noredirect=1&lq=1) about the 'autoheal' ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes.**

Harry Potter once grew his hair back overnight after Aunt Petunia cut it off, while asleep:

> Next morning, however, he had gotten up to find his hair exactly as it had been before Aunt Petunia had sheared it off.
>   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone*, chapter 2</sub>

---

After the clarification of what the OP meant by spell, I'd say that it's possible, but probably not very likely. You would have to make the appropriate motion, and think/sleeptalk the right words, at the same time. It presumably *is* possible, though.

Comment: Isn't this part of the theory that you can't cut a wizards hair? [Here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/94631/68872)

Comment: I didn't accept that answer ;). It obviously grew back magically; you can't have all your hair cut off and have it grow back overnight *without* magic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55840/discussion-between-edlothiad-and-mithrandir).

Comment: It is kind of indicated that Harry did not sleep that night. "Dudley had laughed himself silly at Harry, who spent a sleepless night imagining school the next day, where he was already laughed at for his baggy clothes and taped glasses. Next morning, however, he had gotten up to find his hair exactly as it had been before Aunt Petunia had sheared it off ”

Comment: @Vishvesh - I kinda imagined that as just not sleeping *well*, ie, not falling asleep for a while. That's still called a sleepless night sometimes.

Comment: @Mithrandir I up voted your answer, but I had this confusion.

Comment: Also, @Vishvesh, I find it hard to believe that he could lie awake worrying about it, probably touching his hair (because that's what you do) and not noticing it grew back if he was awake all night.

Comment: I would think sleepless night means not sleeping at all...

Comment: @DoctorWho22 - see the comment directly above yours.

Comment: You are making the assumption that he kept touching his hair though, there's nothing stating that... It's just stated he had a sleepless night which would mean he didn't sleep.

Comment: That's not a "spell," though.  Harry couldn't have intentionally done that awake, let alone asleep.

Comment: @DoctorWho22 - also, the weight. Wouldn't you notice the weigh difference?

Comment: @CHEESE - see the chat discussion.

Comment: Again you are making the assumption that he slept even though it's stated he had a sleepless night.  At this point you are arguing with what's written. He might not have noticed because he spent the entire night thinking about something else.

Comment: @DoctorWho22 - Er what? I'm saying if he *didn't* sleep he would notice. Also, it specifically states that he spent the night thinking about it, so your last line doesn't make sense...

Comment: @DoctorWho22, Mithrandir: please take it to the chatroom linked above.

Comment: Close enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't think so because every time i see them learning or casting a spell, they have to remember to concentrate. Concentrating on the things around them physically would prove difficult while sleeping.

Comment: Can you provide any sources for you answer? It'll bring it more attention.

Comment: The one that comes to mind is when they are practicing the patronas (spellcheck), in the room of requirements. That being said, my wife pointed out that Harry removed the glass from the snakes cage without "trying" to do it.

Answer (score -1):

It might be possible because it's stated in the book series that just simply saying a spell in your mind can properly cast it. I found this quote in the [Why does pronunciation of spells matter?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/116235/68872) question somebody commented earlier and found this quote within one of the answers:

> "Pointing his wand at nothing in particular, he gave it an upward flick and said Levicorpus! inside his head. "Aaaaaaaargh!" There was a flash of light and the room was full of voices: Everyone had woken up as Ron had let out a yell. Harry sent Advanced Potion-Making flying in panic; Ron was dangling upside down in midair as though an invisible hook had hoisted him up by the ankle."

Now if the wizard was sleeping walking and had used the same motion and thought process I would think that it would allow the spell to work like normal. It's also possible to use wandless magic as well, so it might be possible to do some forms of magic while asleep.